# Centripetal Acceleration as a Cross Product

Tags: velocity, vectors, centripetal-force, angular-velocity

Is it fine to express the centripetal acceleration as a cross product?
a=v X w (where a is centripetal acceleration, v is magnitude of velocity, w is angular velocity)

And is it v X w or w X v?

What I think:
Since centripetal acceleration requires tangential (perpendicular) velocity, I start thinking about cross products, and was able to express the acceleration vector as 2 other vectors.
Fiddling around with my right hand, I think that a=v X w and not a=w X v.
Where the convention is
-angular velocity towards me implies positive anticlockwise movement
-centripetal acceleration upwards is taken as positive
-velocity has to move in a way to cause anticlockwise movement

Thing is, I've been searching this up on the Internet but couldn't find any resources for confirmation.

**Is it true that centripetal acceleration can be represented as the cross product of velocity and angular velocity? v X w**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\vec{a}=\vec{\omega} \times \vec{v}$$
This delivers the goods for a point moving at speed $v$ in a circular path with angular velocity $\vec\omega$ about the centre of the circle. Because the circle lies in one plane, the direction of $\vec\omega,$ as well as its magnitude, is constant.

We can indeed derive the centripetal acceleration formula rather neatly starting with
$$\vec{v}=\vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}$$
So$$\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}=\frac{d\vec{\omega}}{dt} \times r + \vec\omega \times \frac{d\vec r}{dt}$$
The first term on the right disappears because $\vec\omega$ is a constant for a body moving in a circle at constant speed, so you're left with$$\vec a=\vec\omega \times \vec v$$

Comment: Rohit's answer, back-substituting $\vec{v}=\vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}$ gives a much neater equation without the cross product or the pseudo-vector $\omega.$

Comment: Why w X v instead of v X w? Actually, it seems to work both ways for the right hand rule.

Comment: Suppose that body is moving anticlockwise on a table top, seen from above. Thus $\vec\omega$ is upwards (using right hand screw rule). Agreed? Consider the instant when the body is East of the circle centre, that is $\vec r$ is Eastwards} So $\vec{\omega} \times \vec r$ is Northwards, confirming that the body really is going anticlockwise. The rest follows by algebra. If you want to check just the final result, consider the same instant for the same set-up and evaluate $\vec{\omega} \times \vec v$. It gives an Eastward vector, that is towards the circle centre.

Comment: My answer and comment assumed a right hand rule for the definition of $\vec\omega$ and for the definition of the vector product. If, instead, we used left hand rules $for\ both,$ we'd get the same result!

Comment: For w X v, w is on my index towards me. v is towards my right on the middle finger. Centripetal acceleration is upwards on thumb. For v X w, v is towards the left on the index finger, w is towards me on my middle finger, centripetal acceleration is still upwards on the thumb. Is there a reason why v has to be towards the right and not the left?

Comment: After typing my response out, I realised that if w is towards me, it has to be an anticlockwise movement caused by a velocity moving right and c. acceleration upwards, instead of velocity moving left with a c. acceleration upwards (it should be downwards). Am I getting this right?

Comment: (a) "v is towards my right on the middle finger. Centripetal acceleration is upwards on thumb. For v X w, v is towards the left " Why are you changing the direction for $v$? (b) You can erase and replace a wrong comment by clicking on the red blob that appears when you sweep the mouse past the end of your comment (c) If I am to help, please use the set-up that I described in the first 3 lines of my comment starting "Suppose...". Then I'll understand what you mean more clearly.

Comment: In my previous comment starting with "w X v", I considered 2 situations: w X v and v X w because the cross product is anticommutative. In the second comment starting with "after typing", I concluded that v X w is wrong and w X v is right, because I thought that both were right initially and I wanted to seek clarification. Also, I believe that I followed your set-up "For w X v". v X w is wrong, and I was trying to check that. It's fine, I now know that centripetal acceleration is w X v and not v X w.

Comment: By the way, I asked this question due to the lack of resources online to confirm this. Sorry if this whole question seems to be rather rudimentary.

Comment: No cause for apology. I'm glad you now understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the right hand rule(convention) for evaluating the cross product, that is $\hat{x}\times\hat{y}=\hat{z}$ for the cartesian co-ordinate unit vectors, then the centripetal acceleration seems to be $\bf{\omega}\times\bf{v}$. Furthermore, it can be simplified to be $\bf{\omega}\times\bf{v}=\bf{\omega}\times[\bf{\omega}\times\bf{r}]=-|\omega|^2\bf{r}$. Refer to the following reference for more details. Hope this answers your question.

Reference: Derivation using vectors https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force

Comment: Why is the centripetal acceleration negative? I know that it is obtained from the vector triple product expansion, but is there another way to explain why it is negative?

Comment: The acceleration is along $-\bf{r}$ direction. This is because, for an object to in the circular motion, it needs to be "pulled" inwards towards the origin(pivot) by some force(for example the tension of a string, gravitational force, etc), which causes an inward acceleration.

Comment: Is the inward acceleration taken as negative by convention?

Comment: yes, you are right. That's the convention, with direction of $\hat{r}$ being radially outward (hence positive), pointing away from the origin.